# Bash Scripting: How to auto start VSC and run a few commands inside integrated terminal?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I work on a large project and I only use ubuntu to run that project.

It's kind of cumbersome for me to open ubuntu, then open VSC, then run `vagrant up` and then run `vagrant ssh` and then run `redis-server` and then run `./run-dev.py`, would it be possible to automate this process?

Thank you for your time :).

Comment: can't you use ubuntu desktop ?

Comment: @error404, I want something that does this whenever I boot into ubuntu, without needing me to initiate it or supervise it. It's just a convenience thing. I don't know if this kind of scripting is possible with VSC and I'm not even sure where to try and go to figure out if it is.

Comment: the best thing would be to use a docker command with volume mount. this will help you to use the docker light weight linux with Visual Studio Code

Comment: I don't think you're getting what I want here. I just want something that starts everytime I boot up this system. I'm not looking for containerization. I do use Ubuntu a lot for other things, just I'm going to be working on this project for a few months and I want it to auto start for me. @error404

Comment: I guess I understood well.  Instead of using vagrant you can use docker with volume mount. You can spin off an ubuntu container with volume mount so that your data is stored locally. You can easily automate this process with a simple bash script. with docker exec you can execute all the commands you need to

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was misleading because I mentioned vagrant. I tagged this with VSC. I want to open up the editor and have the project ready for changes, I think https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events is more along the lines of what I'm looking for. Vagrant is non-negotiable, I'm working on a large project that uses vagrant and it's not worth me trying to redo the env set up.

Comment: Ok now since you have mentioned that vagrant is non-negotiable I will have a look how this can be automated. Certainly it can/should be automated. Meanwhile kindly go through the suggestion below.

Comment: The bellow isn't relevant because I don't want to run something in the VM.
I want to run "vagrant up" and then "vagrant ssh" in VSC integrated terminal, but the suggestion bellow would help me auto start the server, so I can use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a bash script with the commands that you want to be executed after vagrant machine is up and configure Vagrant Provisioner in your case is "shell" inside the Vagrantfile. This way the provisioner executes all the commands that you want once the machine is up and running without needed to ssh in the machine and type them manually. Take a look at Vagrant Provisioner related to shell : https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html